Getting a 404 Error for `meta.json` in Next.js App: How to Resolve?
Hey fellow developers,
I'm encountering an issue while running my Next.js app. The terminal throws a meta.json 404 error, and I'm unsure how to fix it. Here are some additional details:

I created this Next.js app using the command npx create-next-app@latest.
I haven't made any modifications to the project; I simply attempted to run it.
Upon running the app, the terminal displays the meta.json 404 error.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Could someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot and resolve this meta.json 404 error in my Next.js app? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
I've tried the following:

Ensuring all file paths and references are correct.
Verifying the Next.js version and dependencies.
Clearing cache and restarting the development server.

I expected these steps to resolve the meta.json 404 error, but unfortunately, the issue persists. I'm now seeking guidance on further troubleshooting steps or solutions.

Update: I found the solution to this issue!
If you're encountering the meta.json 404 error in your Next.js app while using Chrome, it may be caused by certain browser extensions expecting a meta.json file.
To resolve it, try disabling your Chrome extensions. In my case, removing certain extensions eliminated the error, allowing the app to run smoothly without any 404 issues.
Hope this helps others facing the same problem!
